# Adding Date field in the Registration Form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-breeze

I have an error that says

```
Validation rule date_format requires at least 1 parameters.
```

Then this is my Code under RegisteredUserController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name'=>['required','string','max:255'],
        'sex'=>['required','string','max:10'],
        'birthdate'=>['required','date_format'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.User::class],
        'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'sex'=>$request->sex,
        'birthdate'=>$request->birthdate,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);

    event(new Registered($user));

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

I tried search for similar issues

Comment: i solved it. I change the date_format to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the date_format parameter

```
'date_of_birth' => 'date_format:Y-m-d',
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
'birthdate'=>['required','date_format']
```

to

```
'birthdate'=>['required','date'],
```